# access to kubernetes cluster shows time out

Tags: java, kubernetes

When I try to access the Kubernetes cluster with Java app, I found the connection was timed out. When I try to connect to cluster by `curl http://localhost:8080` or curl `https://localhost:6443`, it shows the connection is refused. I tried to solve this problem but I failed.

Comment: Can you show us the code snippet you are using to access K8s?

Comment: Can you share some yaml of how are you deploying the service?

Answer (score 2):

To access the cluster start the proxy with the command :
   kubectl proxy

[root@master pkg]# kubectl proxy
    Starting to serve on 127.0.0.1:8001

then from another terminal

curl https://127.0.0.1:8001

Other way to do this 
   - Get your IP cluster with the command :
     kubectl cluster-info

```
   for example :

     kubectl cluster-info

     Kubernetes master is running at https://xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:6443
```

then do :
 curl https://xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:6443 --insecure

may be at this point you will find that you have to provide certificates 
 to access the cluster.